What is this type of problem is this?
I have a set of entity types, say colors (red, green, blue, etc.) and a set of groups of entities. E.g. one group may be 3 blue, one may be 2 red and 1 blue, and so on. I have the assumption that groups tend not to intermingle spatially with other groups. All these are known ahead of time. And it's possible we're missing some dots, so each group may not be fully filled.
Given a collection of colored dots and their locations, I want to find all the groups represented in the map and what region of space each covers.
As an example, suppose we define the 3 blue group and the 2 red 1 blue group. Given this distribution of points:

We compose our defined group and the spatial distribution of points and can determine the groups as:

Essentially, we want to optimize the problem both over group membership/definitions and the spatial distribution of points. Since the groups occur in relatively convex shapes, we know that one of middle blue points cannot belong to the group of the left.
I started thinking about some sort of graph clustering. I believe I can define a cost function for each clustering (i.e. cost of clustering a distant point, cost of missing a point, etc.). Then all I would need would be a way to generate guesses for the clustering. But that'd quickly grow difficult as the number of points, groups definitions, and/or colors increases.
I started reading about sub-modular optimization, but I don't see where the diminishing returns occurs. Further, I'm not sure that applies since we have more than two sets?
In short, what are some terms I can search for to better understand this problem?
Thank you very much!

It sounds like a hard problem. Maybe related to mixed integer programming? Also it is not clear how you formalize your assumption that "groups tend not to intermingle spatially with other  groups". In your example it is not clear why 3 horizontal lines would not be an equally good answer.

If the number of points is very small you could try to exhaustively generate all non-crossing set partitions and check if the sets satisfy the required properties...

This definitely sounds like a clustering problem given the fact that you're trying to organize these data points into groups based on spatial distance.

I agree, but in the above example, there's just one cluster.  Clustering alone completely misses the group structure.
